# Whenever I try to install pycrypto errors comes there

Tags: python, visual-studio, compiler-errors, pycrypto

building 'Crypto.Random.OSRNG.winrandom' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
How to fix it pls anyone help

Comment: Don't use pycrypto, its been unsupported for a long time. pycryptodome is the new backwards-compatible library.

Answer (score 0):

Get the "Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools" from here:

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691126&fixForIE=.exe.

After it's installed, reboot and try again.